# firemonkey - How to start mobile Keyboard in lower case letter?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

At my application, there's a text field where the user will type their account e-mail.

With `Java` I can easily make the Android keyboard start with a lower-case letter by using

```
EditText text = new EditText(context);
text.setInputType(android.text.InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | android.text.InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
```

How is it possible to achieve the same with Delphi 10 Seattle?

Comment: Machado, u use firemonkey for programming Android?... i need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there is no easy way to make accurate settings like yours currently. Delphi and java vk types mapping is implemented inside fmx.dex.jar library, embedded by default with every FMX Android project.

But for current purposes you can just set KeyboardType to EmailAddress, which will be converted to TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS combination. And this will be the best decision for Android.

Here are all the mappings.

On Android there is the following mapping between TVirtualKeyboardType values and TJFMXTextEditorProxy.JavaClass constants (see FMX.Platform.Android):

```
  case VirtKBControl.KeyboardType of
    TVirtualKeyboardType.Default:
      KbType := TJFMXTextEditorProxy.JavaClass.INPUT_TEXT;
    TVirtualKeyboardType.NumbersAndPunctuation:
      KbType := TJFMXTextEditorProxy.JavaClass.INPUT_NUMBER_AND_PUNCTUATION;
    TVirtualKeyboardType.NumberPad:
      KbType := TJFMXTextEditorProxy.JavaClass.INPUT_NUMBER;
    TVirtualKeyboardType.PhonePad:
      KbType := TJFMXTextEditorProxy.JavaClass.INPUT_PHONE;
    TVirtualKeyboardType.Alphabet:
      KbType := TJFMXTextEditorProxy.JavaClass.INPUT_ALPHABET;
    TVirtualKeyboardType.URL:
      KbType := TJFMXTextEditorProxy.JavaClass.INPUT_URL;
    TVirtualKeyboardType.NamePhonePad:
      KbType := TJFMXTextEditorProxy.JavaClass.INPUT_NAME_PHONE_PAD;
    TVirtualKeyboardType.EmailAddress:
      KbType := TJFMXTextEditorProxy.JavaClass.INPUT_EMAIL_ADDRESS;
  end;
```

Mapping between TJFMXTextEditorProxy.JavaClass constants and android.text.InputType is the following (it's in fmx.dex.jar):

```
switch (mInputType) {
case INPUT_NUMBER:
    outAttrs.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER;
    break;
case INPUT_NUMBER_AND_PUNCTUATION:
    outAttrs.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT;
    break;
case INPUT_PHONE:
    outAttrs.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE;
    break;
case INPUT_ALPHABET:
    outAttrs.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS;
    if (!mPassword)
        outAttrs.inputType |= InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES;
    break;
case INPUT_URL:
    outAttrs.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_URI;
    break;
case INPUT_NAME_PHONE_PAD:
    outAttrs.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE;
    if (!mPassword)
        outAttrs.inputType |= InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES;
    break;
case INPUT_EMAIL_ADDRESS:
    outAttrs.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS;
    break;
case INPUT_TEXT:
default:
    outAttrs.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT;
    if (!mPassword)
        outAttrs.inputType |= InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES;
    break;          
}

if (mPassword)
{
    if ((outAttrs.inputType & InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER) == InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER)
        outAttrs.inputType |= InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD;
    else
        outAttrs.inputType |= InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What component are you using for representing of this text field?

If you are using TEdit then you can change KeyboardType property to EmailAddress which should start virtual keyboard in lower case.

And based on the OS that your application is started on you could even get custom keyboard layout which provides additional keys for specific characters like @. That is if the target OS does support that.

Answer (score -3):

Although the keyboard will show up with the upper-case key activated, if you set

```
procedure TForm.Edit1Typing(Sender: TObject);
begin

  Edit1.Text:=AnsiLowerCase(Edit1.Text);
  Edit1.GoToTextEnd;

end;
```

Then all typed keys will be in lower-case.

Comment: This answers a different question, and also stops the user from inserting.

Comment: Different question, same expected behavior: avoid the user from typing an upper-case letter on the e-mail address.This is definitely not the best UX approach. Well, I was just trying to help.

Comment: It's actually really poor behaviour because the user thinks they will get an upper case character and don't. Perhaps they want upper case in the address they type.